# AngularJS: ng-click still not working after using "$compile(html)($scope)"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to do something like this:
(1) click 'create' to invoke function 'createGroupForm', and then some html will be prepend to '#user-group-list'
(2) then I type the group name and click the 'ok' button, and the console will print the group name I typed before.

Now I have achieved step 1, but in step 2 function 'createGroup' can't be invoked. So how can I fix this problem?

html:

```
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-app="myApp">
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="authorityController">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <section class="content-header">
        <span class="breadcrumb">
            <a ng-click="createGroupForm($event)"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>create</a>
        </span>
    </section>
        <section class="content" id="user-group-list">

        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller("authorityController",['$compile','$scope','$http','$log','$cookies',function ($compile,$scope,$http,$log,$cookies) {

$scope.groupName = "";

$scope.createGroupForm = function($event){
    var html = '<div class="box box-solid" ng-repeat="groupInfo in groupInfoList">' +
                    '<div class="box-body">' +
                        '<input ng-model="groupName" class="pull-left" placeholder="please type in the group name"/>' +
                        '<span class="pull-right">' +
                        "<button ng-click='createGroup()' class='btn btn-danger pull-right btn-block btn-sm'>Ok</button>" +
                        '</span>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
    var $html = $compile(html)($scope);
    $("#user-group-list").prepend(html);
};

$scope.createGroup = function(){
    $log.log($scope.groupName);
};

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the wrong reference, instead of `$html` you pass `html` to `prepend`

```
var $html = $compile(html)($scope);
$("#user-group-list").prepend(html);
```

should be

```
var $html = $compile(html)($scope);
$("#user-group-list").prepend($html);
```

Comment: I'd advise to setup `eslint` integration within your code editor to immediately show unused variables. That could greatly help to avoid such errors. Other than that nobody's safe, we are all human. :)